# Как правильно сделать скрытый блок, который открывается с права на странице при нажатии кнопки

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. У меня страница трансформируется по медиа запросам, и поисковая панель должна скрыватся с экрана, при нажатии на кнопку прилетать справа. Проблема в том, что я не очень понимаю, почему если я задаю этой панели в медиа запросах

```
position:absolute;
left:500px;
```

моя страница растягивается(появляется горизонтальный скролл), даже если ставлю на body:

```
max-width: 300px (к примеру)
```

Я уже проделал такое с одним блоком, правда он находится сверху и там такие параметры:

```
position: absolute;
top: -300px;
```

Как можно реализовать появляение этого блока нормально? Или просто делать ему

```
display:none
```

пока не нажмется кнопка?

```css
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#test {
  position:absolute;
  left:1000px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="test">test</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: пропишите для body {overflow-x:hidden}

Comment: полоса исчезла, но страница может листаться в право

Comment: а если body {overflow:hidden;overflow-y:auto} ?

Comment: так же прокручивает

Comment: А можете воспроизводимый пример в вопрос добавить?

Comment: Добавил, но проблема в том, что я теструю на телефоне и там мы можем прокручивать пальцем

Comment: в боди добавить обертку с relative потов ней контейнер с absolute?

Comment: @Horchynskyi а вы пробовали предложенный мной вариант применить и/или к html?

Comment: ну я к body применял как вы написали

Comment: @Horchynskyi ну вот я и говорю, попробуйте применить и к html

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а почему у вас блок выезжает слева? При любой разметке и при любых стилях блок, выходящий за пределы контейнера слева, не будет создавать горизонтальную прокрутку

Comment: @максимленский прочитайте внимательно вопрос и мой комментарий. В вашем варианте и без дополнительных обёрток все будет работать

Comment: скролла не надо. как это к html применить?

Comment: html{overflow: hidden;overflow-y: auto;}

Comment: не помогает все так же, да я думаю наверное просто display:none назначить пока кнопка не нажата и все)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Создается с помощью `position: fixed`, `right: -100500px` и `right: 0px` на родительском элементе с помощью динамичного добавления CSS класа.

Пример на Codepen: [Посмотреть пример](https://codepen.io/AndrewKiri/pen/MvgQLo)

```js
var tabElement = document.querySelector(".tab");

tabElement.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  var slideParent = document.querySelector(".slide");
  if (slideParent.className == "slide") {
    slideParent.className += " slide-open";
  } else {
    slideParent.className = "slide";
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  height: 410px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px dashed grey;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  transition-duration: .25s;
}

li:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

.tab {
  background: lightgrey;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35px;
}

.rotate {
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* IE */
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  /* Internet Explorer */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 100px;
}

.slide {
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  right: -200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

.slide.slide-open {
  right: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="tab">
      <p class="rotate">slide me</p>
    </div>
    <h1>A Sidebar</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>One Thing</li>
      <li>Two Thing</li>
      <li>Three Thing</li>
      <li>Four Thing</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```